# Material UI pagination changing color

Tags: reactjs, colors, pagination, material-ui, styling

I am trying to do some pagination, which in theory is working but the colour of the outline and number are coming out black and my background is very dark so it took me a while to even realised it was working because I couldn't see it at first.

I am trying to change the colour of those parts (or at least the colour of the number) however, this is not working. I have tried to follow different suggestions (including `<PaginationItem>`) but none is doing the job.
Does any one has any suggestions? at what is wrong? Thank you in advance!

```js
import React from 'react';
import Pagination from "@material-ui/lab/Pagination";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    selected: {
        color:'#ffffff',
    },
}));

const Paginations = ({ scientistQuestions, paginate, scientistsPerPage }) => {
   const classes = useStyles();

   const pageNumbers = [];
   for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(scientistQuestions / scientistsPerPage); i++) {
       pageNumbers.push(i)
   }
   console.log(pageNumbers)
   const handlePage = (e) => {
       paginate(Number(e.target.innerText));
   }
    
    return ( 
        <div>
            <Pagination  className={classes.root} count={3} variant="outlined" onClick={(e)=> handlePage(e)} color="primary"  />
        </div>      
    );
}
 
export default Paginations;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, you declared a class `selected` but used `classes.root`.

Second, assigning the style to `root` doesn't override the item's color. In order to do that, you need to use the child selector: `.MuiPaginationItem-root` ([source](https://material-ui.com/api/pagination-item/#css))

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  ul: {
    "& .MuiPaginationItem-root": {
      color: "#fff"
    }
  }
}));

export default function BasicPagination() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <Pagination classes={{ ul: classes.ul }} count={10} />;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/matreial-ui-pagination-item-style-ign5e?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: oh, thank you! yes, the root/selected was an editing error here as I was trying both syntax earlier. Thank you so much for the clarification.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Good luck!

Comment: life saver !, needed the same UI, but different colors <3

Comment: How to change the background of of the active li, cause this is changing the background color of the inactive li

Answer (score 1):

You can use **CSS or SASS** to change color.

```
.MuiPagination-root {
  button {
    color: red !important;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the updated version for anyone using the latest version of mui

```
MuiPagination: {
    styleOverrides: {
        root: {
            button: {
                color: '#fff',
            },
        },
    },
}
```